# javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting **Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined**.

**Input field**

```
<input class="form-control text-right" name="amount" maxlength="45" value="${exp.Amount}" onkeyup='evMoneyFormat( e );'  required="required">
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function evMoneyFormat(evt) {
    //--- only accepts accepts number and 2 decimal place value
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode(key);
    var regex = /^[0-9]{1,14}\.[0-9]{0,2}$/; // number with 2 decimal places
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        //--- this prevents the character from being displayed
        if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
 </script>
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Well, what's `e` doing there? I'd suggest adding the event _in JavaScript_

Comment: Do you even need `e` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything to `onkeyup`.

It should just be: `onkeyup='evMoneyFormat()';`.

When your handler is called, if you have provided a parameter to your function (which you have: `evt`), then the event data will automatically be assigned to the parameter.

You can then use `evt` in your handler for the event data.

However, seeing as you've tagged this with jQuery, a simpler way would be:

```
$(".form-control text-right").keyup(function(evt){
  //--- only accepts accepts number and 2 decimal place value
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode(key);
  var regex = /^[0-9]{1,14}\.[0-9]{0,2}$/; // number with 2 decimal places
  if (!regex.test(key)) {
      theEvent.returnValue = false;
      //--- this prevents the character from being displayed
      if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. now i'm not getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined.`. but this validation is not working. i need to type only numbers like 100, 120.25 etc.. but when i type letters in the filed, they are also show. is my code is wrong ?

Comment: @Bishan I believe that's better asked in a separate question than [in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Bishan Your regex is for the entire field, not for a single keystroke.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be(the event object is available in the inlined context as `event` not as `e`)

```
onkeyup='evMoneyFormat( event );'
```

Since you have tagged it with jQuery, use a jQuery event handler instead of inlined one

Comment: This still won't do anything if the OP hasn't defined the variable `event` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that it's not necessary: passing `event` to the handler has no effect.